# BootstrapperApplicationRef contain an unexpected child element 'bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication' error

Tags: .net, wix, bootstrapper, burn

Currently I am working on wix bootstrapper project. Here I have to implement WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication as BootstrapperApplicationRef. But I get error like in the image.

[Error_snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5soL5.png)

My bundle code is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Iam The best" UpgradeCode="d1f7b448-6985-47af-8c8d-8a07fb6d124d"  AboutUrl="http://www.abcd.com"  DisableModify="yes" 
DisableRemove="no">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication
      LogoFile="BundleLogo.jpg"
      SuppressRepair="yes"
      SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeXml" Value="BundleTheme.xml" />
<WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeWxl" Value="BundleHyperlinkTheme.wxl" />
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value="" />

  <Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id='SampleInstaller' SourceFile='$(var.SetupProject1.TargetDir)SetupProject1.msi' Vital='yes'>
  </MsiPackage>
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

How I can fix this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication` comes from Neil Sleightholm's [WiX Extended Bootstrapper Application extension](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/). You must reference the extension's dll (WixBalExtensionExt.dll) in your WiX project.

Comment: I already added WixBalExtension.dll. So as you suggested I added WixBalExtensionExt.dll. Now it shows new error like both the dll's use the same schema. I am using Wix 3.10. Is there any chance it to be any other issue? In Wix 3.10 WixBalExtensionExt.dll is not there. So I downloaded and added it separately.

Comment: @SHK WixBalExtensionExt.dll was not there because it is not a core WiX extension. Based on the "same schema" error you got, Neil must have wrote it as a replacement for the core WixBalExtension provided by WiX. It sounds like you need to remove WixBalExtension from your project.